# OnTouchListener: ActionMove event on different ImageView

Tags: android, android-imageview, touch-event, ontouchlistener

I have a TableLayout contains 16 ImageView (4x4 grid) and i would to implement the sequent behavior:
User tap one imageView, that change his color for give a feedback to user, then he can swipe (without release tap from screen) to other near imageView and all crossed imageView will change color. I show the code i've used. The table is contained inside a Fragment.

This is my listener for check position of swipe:

```
@Override
public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
    float currentX =event.getX();
    float currentY=event.getY();

    switch (event.getAction()) {
    case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN: {
        for(int i=0; i<buttons.length;i++) {
            if(positions[i].contains(currentX, currentY)) {
                buttons[i].setImageResource(R.drawable.grid_button_hover);
                return true;
            }
        }

        return true;
    }
    case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE: {
        for(int i=0; i<positions.length;i++) {
            if(positions[i].contains(currentX, currentY)) {

                buttons[i].setImageResource(R.drawable.grid_button_hover);
                return true;
            }
        }
        return true;
    }
    case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:{
        clearButtons();
        return true;
    }

    }
    return false;
}
```

positions and buttons contains RectF (for each imageView inside grid) and buttons contains ImageView all imageViews.

This is how i set listener on elements:

```
GridListener listener = new GridListener(getActivity(), this,
            positions, buttons);
    for (int i = 0; i < values.length; i++) {
        imageViews[i].setOnTouchListener(listener);
    }
```

My problem is that everywhere i tap, only imageViews[0] change color. And if i swipe, change only imageViews on first row of table. It seems that only X position matches and Y never match.
And each time i swipe, the view that receive touch event remain always the first one tapped
What's wrong?

Answer (score 0):

You are setting the onTouchListener on each ImageView, and then returning true, which captures the touch event and prevents the other ImageViews from picking it up.  I believe it should work if you just return false from onTouch(), but let me know if that doesn't work.

Comment: I need to keep a single listener for all imageviews. So the problem was that i doesn't consider the space between imageViews and other views before, so values were wrong